# Creating a simple ruby gem that allows the user to call a defined method?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've been looking for some tutorials on creating ruby gems, but all seem to be overly complicated. Essentially, all I want is to make a gem that (**trivial example alert**) allows the user to place a method `add_one(x)` in their code, once the gem is installed.

A lot of tutorials explain how you can call the gem's methods with `Classname.method()`, but that's really not what I want. RyanB has a good example [here](https://github.com/ryanb/uniquify), but again I can't get it to work - mainly because of the 3 lines of code at the bottom of uniquify.rb that read.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  include Uniquify
end
```

In my case, my main module is called AddOne, so how would I go about doing this? Again, sorry for the trivial example, I'm just looking to get started so that my gems will allow the user to call plain ol' methods, without specifying Modules or Classes. In Ryan's example, he's able to simple call `uniquify()` in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example given, he can call `uniquify` as a method because he is calling it inside a class which includes `ActiveRecord::Base`. (He calls `uniquify` inside the `class Product < ActiveRecord::Base`...`end` block) There isn't any real magic here.

To my understanding, what you desire is easily achievable, but isn't a good idea, 'best practice' considered.  You can define anything you want in your gem.  For instance, I could package a file called `say_hello.rb` inside a gem called `salutations`.

**say_hello.rb**

```
def say_hello
  puts "Hello everybody"
end
```

By requiring the packaged gem `salutations` I would gain access to anything defined therein.  However, it might lead to unexpected consequences.  Do what you need to do, but just understand that it might not be the best idea.  Hence, you build things into classes or modules to contain them, and to prevent conflicts with other code.  Good luck.